# Looking for a software which can help me grep and tail logs files on remote machines via a centralized UI or CLI

Tags: logging, grep

I have many applications (distributed in nature) deployed across dozens of virtual machines (mostly Linux). For any new feature development or debugging of production issues I had to login (via SSH) to many of these machines and look at respective logs. It is very time consuming to login to all machines and then look at respective logs, and I want something like a centralized user interface where I can quickly search logs on all remote machines.

While there exist solutions like ELK, Splunk, etc. which provides many great features on log parsing, analysis, visualization and alerting, my requirement is simple to quickly identify patterns in remote logs for troubleshooting and not have to setup big stacks like ELK, Splunk where I have to maintain central server and allocate enough storage to persist remote logs for analysis.

searched for open source projects but not found the one I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I myself wrote programs to help on grep and tail of logs from remote machines. There are two programs, one agent which should be running on remote machines and a server UI running on a central machine. The details are capture here: https://mchopker.github.io/blogs/remote_log_grep_and_tail_via_a_centralized_UI/